# C# Winforms multiple objects class problem

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a simple game using c# windows forms. I have a class named `Enemy` based on the `PictureBox`. I placed a Label named `Display` inside the class. Now I can easily put an Enemy on a form.

I tried am placing an Enemy inside a tab control, but I am not able to make this Label appear. I have already declared it, set the `TabIndex`, `Location` and the `size`.

How can I make the Label show on the screen?

```
class Enemy : PictureBox
{
    public Label Display;

    public void CreateDisplay()
    {
        Display = new Label();

        Display.AutoSize = true;
        Display.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(298, 120);
        Display.Name = "test";
        Display.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        Display.TabIndex = 3;
        Display.Text = "test";
    }
}
```

This is the class code. I call the `CreateDisplay()` function when the user clicks on the object.

Comment: IMHO: inherit from UserControl instead and then put a PictureBox and Label onto the UserControl. Visual Studio has Designer support for UserControls.

Comment: If you want make a simple game, you can use a Panel control and manage the Paint event. Create multiple classes (Game, Board, Enemy...) and invoke their OnDraw methods with the Graphics object that you have in Paint event of panel. Control class is heavier than using only one Panel control and you have more control over that you want to draw. Look for GDI functions for more samples and information.

Comment: Missing: `this.Controls.Add(Display);`.  You can only see child controls that have a parent.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the new Label is not part of the control tree on the form. That is, when painting the form .Net will start with the form itself, then look inside the form's `.Controls` collection, then for each control look inside their `.Controls` collections, and so on. Just because this Label is a member of the `Enemy` type does **not** make it part of that Controls collection. Moreover, a `PictureBox` does not really support adding child controls.

Instead, create a new `UserControl` or custom control based on a `Panel`. This new control should have both a `PictureBox` and a `Label` and childs of this new control. Do this right, and the PictureBox and Label will both be members of the appropriate Controls collection and show on the screen as expected.

Comment: PictureBox supports child controls just fine.  Any control does.  That the designer doesn't encourage it is intentional, it makes overlapping controls easy to do.